# Servlet/EJB Container vs Spring Container

Tags: spring, websphere, tomcat5.5

If this is right [Spring vs EJB. Can Spring replace EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779169/spring-vs-ejb-can-spring-replace-ejb).

My question: **Is Spring a super set of App Server ?**

If Spring(open source) is a container which is a good alternative of EJB container, then what is the use of app severs like WAS(read licensed),WebLogic(read open source) ?
and if need web container, we can use tomcat5/6

assumption: tomcat 7 is not used as a app server in Prod env and one is good to go with Spring(rather than EJB)

Comment: i got a link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-stuff/jboss-vs-tomcat-and-spring-the-never-ending-battle, but not convinced with authors POV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, spring is not a super set of an application server.  Spring relies on some kind of underlying server (something you can start/stop, like Tomcat, WebSphere, WebLogic, etc.), and for most practical purposes, Spring relies on that server having a servlet container, too.