# What are the best technology to replace EJB and EJB Timerservice?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, timer-jobs

we have a application developed using  EJB 2.0.
we used stateless session beans with ejb timer service. we planned to remove completely ejb but we need the timer service. i come to know JMS provide the timer service, but looking for robust technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an alternative to EJBs I'll probably recommend the [Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779169/spring-vs-ejb-can-spring-replace-ejb)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks most popular timer framework is [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/),and it's very easy to integrate with Spring Framework

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring/Quartz, but to keep the things as portable as posible let me suggest you jump in EJB 3.2 (Java EE7). The timer service is simpler and the entire EJB was improved (no more XML). You are familiar with EJB, currently is a good alternative taking into the count your familiarity with the frameworks.